# How to improve website view on search engines

Tags: php, search, web, seo

i would like to know how to provide a more comprehensive view of my website when searched on engines like google, yahoo, etc.

For Example: I searched about namecheap in google and this is how their website result came up.

[image]

i would like my website to be represented like this. Sorry if my question was not presented well.

Comment: Been there... As far as I researched it about a year ago, this is not something that you can create. It's google that does it. All you can do is to give the searchengine a map of how your page is set up using webmastertools. After that, I think it's "top pages" that get that look

Comment: @Andreas Thanks man, ive lost a whole load of curiosity now

Comment: These are sitelinks : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article about [sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en&ref_topic=4589289) from Google.

From that article:

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to
>   the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms
>   to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your
>   site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.

So, you cant fully control it. You should follow the best SEO guidelines and if Google Sitelink's algorithm finds your site good for showing **sitelinks**, it will do so.